# How to accept an object in a __init__ statement of another?

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, object

I'm trying to make a Pokemon simulator, and I'm trying to pass a Type object into my Move object, but I don't understand how to pass this off.

```
class Type:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name="fire"
        self.atNOR=1
        self.atFIG=1
        self.atFLY=1
        self.atPOS=1
        self.atGRO=1
        self.atROC=1
        self.atBUG=1
        self.atGHO=1
        self.atFIR=1
        self.atWAT=1
        self.atGRA=1
        self.atELE=1
        self.atPSY=1
        self.atICE=1
        self.atDRA=1
class Move:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "tackle"
        self.power= 0
        self.ability= "none"
        self.type= normal
```

This just tells me normal isn't a data type, I don't know how to make this line define this normal variable as a Type

Comment: What exactly is `normal`? Could you include its definition into the code snippet?

Comment: Actually in python, type of an object is an object itself. Now what you expect to put in `self.type`?

Comment: normal is supposed to be a default Type for the Move object.

Comment: @Kasramvd I would like to put  a Type object in self.type

Comment: @Dad You didn't passed the `normal` to your constructor and don't defined it anywhere, so it would raise a `NameError`. If you want to set a type object or anything  on an attribute in your class you need to defined it before or passed to your `__init__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have "Type" object as an attribute in Move object, you'll need to use "composition pattern" (so Move has-a Type):

```
class Move:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "tackle"
        self.power = 0
        self.ability = "none"
        self.type = Type()
```

More about composition / inheritance [here](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex44.html)

LearnPythonTheHardway is not always very good resource to learn Python, but in this topic is quite well actually.

Be careful though using "Type" as a class name. Lowercase `type` is actually built-in Python class that can be used as a construct to meta-class programming (or creating classes in general).